# Как убрать лишние пункты из панели Quick Switch Project в Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Сами файл проекта `.sublime-project` и `.sublime-workspace` уже удалены. Но в списке быстрого выбора проектов (Quick Switch Project, `Ctrl+Alt+P` в linux) проект остался:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне он не нужен, как удалить его оттуда?

Comment: Для чего это нужно делать?

Comment: При удалении или перемещении проектов - список быстрого переключения между ними в саблайме захламляется неактуальными пунктами, а при перемещении проектов - дубликатами, одним рабочим и одним нерабочим.

Comment: Вопрос некорректно сформулирован.  // **1.** Согласно условиям вопроса Вам необходимо убрать не «проект», а рабочие пространства проектов, линии с путями к  файлам `.sublime-workspace`, а не `.sublime-project`. // **2.** `Alt+P` открывает пункт Menu Bar `Project`, откуда запускаются команды для управления проектами. Называть его «списком быстрого выбора проектов» на мой взгляд некорректно. «Список быстрого выбора проектов» — это, скорее, `Quick Switch Project` — `Ctrl+7, Ctrl+Alt+P`. // Спасибо.

Comment: **1.** Панель называется quick switch project, и пункты называются `xxx.sublime-project`. Поэтому я использовал термин "проект". Хотя удалять нужно пути до `.sublime-workspace`. **2.** В линуксе сочетание для quick switch project - Alt+P, не знал, что в винде оно отличается. Уточню это в вопросе.

Comment: **1.** У меня в `Switch Project` как раз файлы `.sublime-workspace` содержались... Корректнее примерно так сформулировать на мой взгляд: «Как убрать лишние пункты из панели Switch Project?» // **2.** `Alt+P` не может быть по умолчанию, поскольку мнемоническая `p` должна использоваться для вызова пункта Menu Bar — `Project`. Сейчас проверил в `Default (Linux).sublime-keymap`, какой шорткат используется для данной команды в Linux: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+p"], "command": "prompt_select_workspace" },`. Тот же самый. Возможно, Вы переназначили горячие клавиши? // Спасибо.

Comment: (В прошлое сообщение не влезло.) [**Скриншот**](http://i.imgur.com/99eeq2T.png), показывающий, что в Switch Panel `sublime-workspace` файлы также отображаются.

Comment: По горячей клавише - спасибо, действительно давным давно изменил сочетание. Исправил в вопросе это и название. Также прикрепил свой скриншот - `.sublime-project` в списке, такое и в линуксе и в windows. Странная ситуация, конечно.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в Windows, оказывается, вообще нет по умолчанию хоткея `"prompt_select_workspace"`, я также сам задал. // Да, и если быть точным, панель называется `Switch Project`, а `Quick Switch Project` — это пункт меню. // Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот список строится по данным в файле сессии саблайма. Нужно открыть файл сессии и удалить оттуда путь до уже удаленного `.sublime-workspace`-файла.

Для этого:

#### 1. Найдите файл `Session.sublime_session`

Откройте Sublime Text. Перейдите в меню `Preferences - Browse Packages`. Перейдите на уровень выше - увидите папки `Local`, `Packages`. Перейдите в `Local`. Там будет файл `Session.sublime_session`.

- В linux путь подобен такому:

  `/home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session`
- В windows:

  `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\Session.sublime_session`

#### 2. Закройте Sublime Text

Иначе саблайм не даст сохранить измененный файл `Session.sublime_session`.

#### 3. Измените `Session.sublime_session` в любом текстовом редакторе

Найдите секцию `recent_workspaces`. В ней будет список путей до всех ваших `.sublime-workspace`-файлов. Удалите нужные, сохраните файл. Запускайте Sublime Text.

Comment: Такое не должно правиться вручную. Добавил [**feature request**](https://github.com/randy3k/ProjectManager/issues/58) к плагину ProjectManager. Спасибо.